# boost address_v4::from_string() crashed

Tags: boost, crash, boost-asio

address_v4::from_string() crashed when I passed empty string or invalid address

```
address_v4 address = address_v4::from_string("");
```

boost version: 1_53

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't in fact crash. It just throws an exception as documented:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    try {
    auto address = boost::asio::ip::address_v4::from_string("");
    } catch(std::exception const& e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints "Invalid argument". That's because the argument is not valid. "" is not a valid address.

### Without exceptions

You can opt to use the overloads taking `error_code` to avoid throwing exceptions:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c1a3424db6f6c0f)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    auto address = boost::asio::ip::address_v4::from_string("", ec);
    if (!ec)
        std::cout << "Address: " << address << '\n';
    else
        std::cout << "Error: " << ec.message();
}
```